# Substring in array string

Tags: c#, arrays, substring

I have an array:
`var array = ["19991229", "19801001", "19890123"]`

Then, I want to show this array in a webbrowser form c# by using
`string.Join("<br>", array)`

How can I get the first 4 digit using substring?
I want it print:

1999
1980
1989

I can't use `string.Join("<br>", array).substring(0,4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with Linq:

```
var array = new [] { "19991229", "19801001", "19890123" };

var joinedString = string.Join(
    "<br>",
    array.Select(s => s.Substring(0, 4)));
```

### Bonus Edit:

It looks like those strings are actually dates, so here's some extra code to convert them all to `DateTime` objects:

```
var dates = array.Select(s => new DateTime(
        int.Parse(s.Substring(0, 4)),
        int.Parse(s.Substring(4, 2)),
        int.Parse(s.Substring(6, 2)))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var stArray = new string[] { "19991229", "19801001", "19890123" };
 string stringValue = String.Join("<br>", stArray.Select(x => x.Substring(0,4)));
```